# Rejected inbound migration not behaving as expected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, migration, migration-rejection

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714149) appears to have fallen through the cracks of the migration-rejection system. I believe it should by now have been auto-deleted on SO, in the same way that [its source post](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1905) (requires 10k on windowsphone.se) has been, as this is what's supposed to happen to rejected migrants after 30 days (or a month?)

I note also that that the revision history for [the two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16714151/revisions) (requires 10k on SO) shows that they were *locked* by Community♦ at the time of question closure; but they are both now *deleted*, without that event showing in the revision history.

The question being now **locked**, even as a 10k user I cannot either delete it or even edit it to give it a real tag.

<sup>I found this question during one of my irregular trawls of [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged), a fun game any SO-10k can play...</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [the rules for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year):

> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...**
>
> ...
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

So the source post was deleted after 30 days, as it was closed and migrated to a different site. The destination - where the migration was rejected - was not, since it was not migrated. Note that if the migration had been rejected *within the 30 days*, the original would not have been deleted either (unless it also qualified for deletion under a different rule).

There was a bug for a while that would result in the deletion of both the migrated *and* rejected stubs; this was fixed back in June.

Due to the locking, it might be worth adding an additional rule for deletion to cover some of these questions, however care must be taken to avoid automatic deletion of both sides of a migration without regard to other factors. For now, if you see a rejected migration that should be deleted, just flag for moderator attention and note this under "other".